# how to make an arraylist consistent in java

Tags: java, arraylist

How can we make an ArrayList in java consistent. Means when I have updated the ArrayList in one function, it is updated. But, after the exit from that function it is again setting it's size to 0.

```
public static ArrayList<Vehicle> al=new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    java.util.Iterator<Vehicle> itr= al.iterator();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean addVehicleToSlot(Vehicle vehicle) {
        if((vehicle.slotNo<=0||vehicle.slotNo>40)&&(vehicle.getVehicleType()!="Car"
                ||vehicle.getVehicleType()!="Truck"||vehicle.getVehicleType()!="Two Wheeler")){
            new InvalidSlotException("Slot alraedy allotted");
            return false;
        }
        int iter=0;
        int len=al.size();
        if(len==0){
            al.add(vehicle);
            return true;
        }
        while(iter< len){
            Vehicle veh=(Vehicle)itr.next();
            if(veh.getSlotNo()==vehicle.getSlotNo()){
                new SlotNotFoundException("No slot allotted");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                al.add(vehicle);
                for(Vehicle vehi:al){
                    System.out.println(al);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My function call is this:

```
    Vehicle v1=new Vehicle(o1,"ts75","Truck",37,48);
    ParkingManagement p1=new ParkingManagement();
    System.out.println(p1.addVehicleToSlot(v1));
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Please don't use [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: Also: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I recommend not to store the slot inside the vehicle object. It just does not belong there... It is a property of the `ParkingManangement`, isn't it?

Comment: This is not the complete code. Make sure that the scope of the arraylist is bigger than this function if you want to see that getting updated

Comment: You don't need an iterator here, I think, if you just want the `addVehicleToSlot` method to simply add a vehicle to a list.

Comment: @jwenting It is now, as Jens updated the question to not use raw types.

Comment: There is no apparent value to looping here. Just store the vehicles in a `Map<Integer, Vehicle>` (or a `List<Vehicle>` where vehicles are inserted at their slot index, or even `Vehicle[]`), then you can look up directly if a slot is already assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an iterator at the initialization of your `class`. At this point `al` is probably empty. Leaving you with an empty iterator. As you're never updating the iterator. You will never iterate the list, and thus: The list stays empty.

So replace the use of `iter` with an enhanced for-loop. Also you seem to want to `throw` exceptions but you actually never throw them. At last you're comparing Strings with `==` but this will mostly not work, because `==` will not check on string equality, but the reference. And this may be not allways true for two strings that seem *equal*. Use `.equals()` instead:

```
public boolean addVehicleToSlot(Vehicle vehicle) {
    if((vehicle.slotNo <=0 || vehicle.slotNo > 40) && (!vehicle.getVehicleType().equals("Car") || !vehicle.getVehicleType().equals("Truck") || !vehicle.getVehicleType().equals("Two Wheeler"))){
        throw new InvalidSlotException("Slot alraedy allotted");
    }

    if(al.isEmpty()){ // instead of al.size() == 0, just use al.isEmpty()
        al.add(vehicle);
        return true;
    }

    for(Vehicle veh : al){
        if(veh.getSlotNo() == vehicle.getSlotNo()){
            throw new SlotNotFoundException("No slot allotted");
        } else{
            al.add(vehicle);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would imagine you intend to add the vehicle after the loop. Otherwise, it isn't going to loop very far (it will either throw or return on the first iteration).

Comment: @AndyTurner in fact I am not sure what the OP wants to achieve with this. The whole looping doesn't really makes sense.

Comment: If the array is empty then the iterator never will be used so it’s not a problem that it’s empty.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, but after the first insert there will still no iteration happen. Because `itr` is still an empty iterator. Making the impression that the List is *empty*

Comment: Ok, that’s a fair point. We don’t really know when and in what scope it gets initialized but maybe you’re right.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson According to the code OP's dumped, it seems that it is declared on class level. But I might be wrong. This question is highly unclear

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors and issues you need to take account of:

- I don't think you understand how iterators work. They are generally very short term variables: declare, iterate, dispose. There are a few use cases for long lasting iterators but this isn't one of them.
- In fact explicit iterators are not commonly needed these days: you can use a for-each or `Stream` for most situations.
- Your logic seems to imply that there can be only one vehicle with a given 'slot' in the list. If that's the case there are much better ways of handling this:

Use a map to store your slots:

```
Map<Integer,Vehicle> slotMap;
```

Check with a stream:

```
if (al.stream().anyMatch(v -> v.getSlotNr() == vehicle.getSlotNr()))
    ...
```